# Flutter - ListView wrapped by Listener

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview

```
Listener(
        onPointerUp: (event) {
                   LogUtil.v('++++++onPointerUp++++');
},
        child: ListView.builder(
               itemCount:10,
                itemBuilder:(context, index) {
                   return GestureDetector(
                          onTap:() {
                              LogUtil.v('++++++GestureDetector++++');
                          },
                          child:Container(
                             height:200
                          )
                    )
                }
))
```

When I click listview item, print '++++++GestureDetector++++' ,'++++++onPointerUp++++' also printed. How can I make '++++++onPointerUp++++' not print?

Comment: can you describe why you are using both the listener and GestureDetector?

Comment: @SujanGainju some reasons, I use listener to listen listview's scroll behavior.

Comment: if you just want to listen to scroll behavior, you could use the `scroll controller` in the `listview.builder`

Comment: @SujanGainju but scroll controller seems cannot listen scroll end behavior

Comment: you could find the end as `_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the log inside the Listener, why don't you just remove the line:

```
LogUtil.v('++++++onPointerUp++++');
```

Comment: I believe the main issue is not about the logging but that he doesn't want the `onPointerUp` to trigger when the `onTap` triggers. But yeah, OP should have been more specific

Comment: @Ivo yes you are right, do you have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is a possibility

```
bool tapped = false;

Listener(
        onPointerUp: (event) {
                 if (!tapped ) {
                   LogUtil.v('++++++onPointerUp++++');
                 } else {
                   tapped = false;
                 }
},
        child: ListView.builder(
               itemCount:10,
                itemBuilder:(context, index) {
                   return GestureDetector(
                          onTap:() {
                              tapped = true;
                              LogUtil.v('++++++GestureDetector++++');
                          },
                          child:Container(
                             height:200
                          )
                    )
                }
))
```